# PayPal nvp SetExpressCheckout fails on local development machine

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal

I have recently found out that the PayPal nvp protocols are/will be changing - to require SHA-256 and a Verisign G5 certificate.
It appears that my hosted server environment has the prerequisites in place, because the PayPal process is working fine there.

It is my development machine where the problem exists.
The machine is Windows 7, fully patched up, and should by default have SHA-256 installed.
I have installed the "VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5 root certificate" on the machine. One thing that may be an issue is that when I examine the certificate store with certmgr.msc it show the certificate, but the title bar states [Certificates - Current User]. I am not sure how to examine whether the certificate applies to the machine or just the current user, or whether that matters.

When I run curl -V on this machine, I get the following:

```
C:\Users\me>c:\soft\curl\curl -V
curl 7.33.0 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.33.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8y zlib/1.2.8 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate Largefile NTLM SSL SSPI libz
```

When I run the following curl test with the PayPal nvp endpoint, I get the following:

```
C:\Users\me>c:\soft\curl\curl --insecure https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp  -d  "USER=truncated&PWD=truncated&SIGNATURE=truncated&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=78
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=19&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&cancelUrl=http://www.example.com/cancel.html&returnUrl=http://www.example.com/success.html"
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

The "alert handshake failure" error message is pointed to by the PayPal [SSL Certificate Upgrade Microsite](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1766&viewlocale=en_US&direct=en), but I have tried what I can to make sure SHA-256 and the new root certificate are installed.
Can you point me in the next direction to get my development machine back to working order with PayPal?
Is there any way to identify if the machine has all the requirements in place?

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a PHP version issue. My local machine was on version 5.3.16, and as soon as I upgraded it to 5.6.17 everything started working again.